# Calculating a line integration

Tags: calculus, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I need to calculate the constant alpha so that the integral be independent of the path we take.

$$\int_C [x \ln{(x² + 1)}\;+\;(x² + 1)y]dx + \alpha[\frac{x³}{3} + x + \sin{y}]dy$$

Answer: $\alpha = 1$

My solution:

To find the value of alpha, We need, first, define the vectorial field as a simply connected (has no singularities). If we look at the field, it has nothing that restrict the domain of the field. So, it can be considered as a simply connected field.

My doubt: I got stuck in the next step. I don't know if I need to find a potential function for the vectorial field to determine $\alpha$ or if I need to take another path to calculate this.

Comment: For $2D$ vector field, if the line integral is $\displaystyle \int_C P dx + Q dy$, you need to check value of $\alpha$ for which $Q_x = P_y$

Comment: Ok. Thanks @MathLover. I'll try this.

Comment: Thanks @MathLover. It works. But I don't understand one thing. Is required to assume the field is conservative ($rot \vec{\mathcal{F}} = \vec{0}$ & field simply connected) for the integral be independent of whatever path are taken? I was thinking about this and I reach a conclusion that the only thing that its required to calculate $\alpha$ is if the field is simply connected. Can you explain more of this solution please?

Comment: Please see https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcIII/conservativevectorfield.aspx for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A differential, $\alpha(x,y)dx+ \beta(x,y)dy$ is independent of the path if and only if it is an "exact differential"- that there is a function, f such that $df= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial} dy= \alpha(x,y)dx+ \beta(x,y)dy$ which means that $\alpha(x,y)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\beta(x,y)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.  Then $\int_a^b df= f(b)- f(a)$ no matter what the path from a to b is.

If we differentiate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ with respect to y we get $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}= \frac{\partial \alpha(x,y)}{\partial y}$.
If we differentiate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ with respect to x we get $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x}= \frac{\partial \beta(x,y)}{\partial x}$.

For any "reasonably nice" functions that "mixed" deriatives are equal so we get the "cross condition" $\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}= \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}$.

Here, that means that we must have $x^2+ 1= \alpha(x^2+ 1)$ so $\alpha= 1$.

Comment: Thanks @user247327. Now, I really understood this thing. Very nice.